# How to test a server side debugOnly package

Tags: testing, meteor, tinytest

I don't understand how it is possible to test a package that is debugOnly.
My `package.js` is quite simple :

```
 Package.describe({
  name: 'lambda',
  version: '0.0.1',
  debugOnly: true // Will not be packaged into the production build
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');
  api.addFiles('lambda.js');
  api.export("Lambda", 'server');
});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('tinytest');
  api.use('lambda');
  api.addFiles('lambda-tests.js', 'server');
});
```

My `lambda-test.js` :

```
Tinytest.add('example', function (test) {
  test.equal(Lambda.func(), true);
});
```

My `lambda.js` :

```
Lambda = {
     func: function() {
         return "Christmas";
     }
}
```

When I run `meteor test-packages`, it just fails : **Lambda is not defined.** If I remove the `debugOnly: true` the test pass. So how can I test my package using tinytest ? 
Or this is a bug !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue!  It turns out the tests are working fine.  The Lambda is not getting exported in the project either.

from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/0f0c5d3bb3a5492254cd0843339a6716ef65fce1/tools/isobuild/compiler.js

```
// don't import symbols from debugOnly and prodOnly packages, because
// if the package is not linked it will cause a runtime error.
// the code must access them with `Package["my-package"].MySymbol`.
```

Try:

```
Tinytest.add('example', function (test) {
  //also changed expected value from true to Christmas to make test pass
  test.equal(Package['lambda']['Lambda'].func(), "Christmas");
  //you can use Package['lambda'].Lambda as well, but my IDE complains
});
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
if (Package['lambda']) {
  console.log("we are in debug mode and we have lamda");
  console.log("does this say Christmas? " + Package['lambda']["Lambda"]['func']());

} else {
  console.log("we are in production mode, or we have not installed lambda");
}
```

Comment: I will try it and comes back to you ! ;-)